# How to search in paragraph style in indesign by script

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, javascript

i'm bad in JS, i asked one of my friend to help me in that, also, if you can give me your hand here this will be good too.

I have this code, which it's make search for the paragraph by give it the name of the paragraph.

```
    var doc = app.activeDocument,
    myParagraphStyle = doc.paragraphStyles.itemByName('.Vig P');

// example of changing some properties
myParagraphStyle.properties = {
    composer: 'Adobe World-Ready Paragraph Composer',
    appliedFont: 'Calibri',
    appliedLanguage: 'Arabic',
    underline: false,
    tracking: 0.015,
    
}
```

i change the attributes whenever i want.

the issue or my request is to make this script go through the styles in the file instead of searching by one by one.

is that ok?

Also,
I have other question, Can i make this like in visual, Like design with the attributes (whatever i insert/delete) converted to Checkboxes or text values in GUI to be done instead of changes the values in code every time?

I hope this be clear and i'm welcome with any question to clear my point more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to loop through the styles but aren't sure how? If that's the case, [this may be useful](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/looping-through-paragraph-styles/td-p/8569638)